# Fill in Color by Compare Two Different keywords

Tags: excel, vba

I want to fill in color entire row by compare two column with different cell text. As shown in image below, If I enter input at column1 "PAID" and at column2 "DONE". I want entire row fill in green colour.

[image]

My code is:

```
Dim itm As Range
Dim rw As Long
With Sheets("PO 2019_Vendor")
rw = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If .Range("AG" & rw).Value = "PAID" And .Range("AJ" & rw).Value = "DONE" Then itm.EntireRow.Interior.Color = 4

If .Range("AG" & rw).Value = "PAID" And .Range("AJ" & rw).Value = "NOTRCV" Then itm.EntireRow.Interior.Color = 6

If .Range("AG" & rw).Value = "PENDING" And .Range("AJ" & rw).Value = "DONE" Then itm.EntireRow.Interior.Color = 28

End With
End Sub
```

I hope you understand my explanation and will help me out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to set `itm`

Comment: It looks like conditional formulas would be your solution. `=AND($AG1="PAID",$AJ1="DONE")` and the likes with Fill set to the correct color.

Answer (score 1):

If that columns are `AG` and `AJ`, and headers are in first row:

```
Sub erf()
Dim itm As Range
Dim rw As Long

    With Sheets("PO 2019_Vendor")

        rw = .Range("AG" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To rw 'only if your headers are in 1 row

        If .Range("AG" & i).Value = "PAID" And .Range("AJ" & i).Value = "DONE" Then Rows(i).Interior.Color = 4

        If .Range("AG" & i).Value = "PAID" And .Range("AJ" & i).Value = "NOTRCV" Then Rows(i).EntireRow.Interior.Color = 6

        If .Range("AG" & i).Value = "PENDING" And .Range("AJ" & i).Value = "DONE" Then Rows(i).EntireRow.Interior.Color = 28

        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This answers half the question, I'm afraid. `Color` property takes a `Long` value representing an RGB. Furthermore (more offtopic), if you have to loop through a range, I prefer to use `For Each`, as it is significantly faster then the `For i` loop (on a larger dataset). + 1 either way =).

Comment: Yea, my bad, it should have been `ColorIndex` for numbers like in code. Wow, thanks for that info about `For each`, really appreciate that, also for point+1 :)

Comment: Watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NSP8usCrcvs) video on the difference in speed (from 6:50 onwards). Maybe less noticable looping through a range object (so my earlier statement it being significantly faster on a range object was false, however it still is faster.)

Comment: That's why I love SO and its community, this was very useful lesson, once again thank You @JvdV for that, really, really appreciate this.

Answer (score 1):

Two things I would suggest:

- Loop through an `Array`: As I don't know the amount of rows your would want to loop through, arrays should be significantly faster.
- Don't use the `Color` property when using color indexes. You either want to use `Color` or `ColorIndex`. The former takes a `Long` value representing a RGB color (or the RGB(...,...,...) syntax itself. The latter takes a color index from within your currently selected color theme. Mixing `Color` property with an index number will paint the row black. I assume this is what you try to do.

---

```
Sub ColorRows()

Dim arr As Variant
Dim rw As Long, x As Long

With Sheet1 'Change according to your sheet's CodeName (see Project Explorer)
    rw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AG").End(xlUp).Row
    arr = .Range("AG1:AJ" & rw)
    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(x, 1) = "PAID" And arr(x, 4) = "DONE" Then .Rows(x).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        If arr(x, 1) = "PAID" And arr(x, 4) = "NOTRCV" Then .Rows(x).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        If arr(x, 1) = "PENDING" And arr(x, 4) = "DONE" Then .Rows(x).Interior.ColorIndex = 28
    Next x
End With

End Sub
```